# Identify the built language while installing and uninstalling

Tags: wix

I made a installer and build it from 4 diferent languages.

I need to run a external exe (a installer for another application) while installing and uninstalling. that exe also have made fore same 4 different languages.

Now i want to run these executable according to the language of my msi. 
and also i need to run it again (uninstaller for that app) while my application uninstalling.

Can anyone give me a hint how to that on WIX?
Can i get the built language id while run my installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have post this question to the WIX user mailing list too. based on someones idea there I added a string to the locale file.

```
<String Id="Culture" Overridable="no">en-US</String>
```

and used it like `!(loc.Culture)`

It may not the best idea, but it does the work.